# Save Facebook credentials on React Native and Firebase

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native-fbsdk

I'm really new to React Native. My intention is that by storing the credentials provided by FBSDK's loginWithReadPermissions, the user won't have to log in each time the app launches, but just one time after it is first installed. Maybe store it somewhere I can check the credentials in componentWillMount().

My first question is: does the FBSDK do this automatically? If not, how can I do this?

I have this code for Facebook Auth:

```
facebookAuthentication(callback){
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'user_likes', 'email']).then(
  function(result) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Inicio de sesión cancelado');
    } else {
      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((accessTokenData) =>{
        const credential = Firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessTokenData.accessToken);
        Firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then((result) =>{
          return callback;
        }, (error) =>{
          console.log('Error en firebase' + error);
        });
      }, (error) =>{
        console.log('ACCESS TOKEN ERROR: ' + error);
      });
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log('Login failed with error: ' + error);
  }
);
```

}

The code works perfectly, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried JavaScript's localStorage? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React Native you can use [Asyncstorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html), which is basically what localstorage is for the web realm: a key-value pair mini-database. 
Actually, you can retrieve the currently logged in user using Firebase's `firebase.auth().currentUser`. Maybe you can check on app startup if it returns a valid user object.